# jQuery conditional chaining

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following jQuery code. It works great, but then I need to include the `.after($('<div />'))` only if `var insertAfter` equals true. Is there an elegant jQuery way of doing this?

```
$('#whatEver')
    .parent()
    .show()
    .width(123)
    .addClass('bebo')
    .before($('<div />'))
    .after($('<div />'))
    .parent()
    .addClass('bla');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this using ternary operator:

```
.after(insertAfter ? $('<div />') : '')
```

Comment: Thanks antyrat,  Was thinking of that.  Any downfalls to inserting `''` into the DOM?

Comment: jQuery `after` method accepts strings as well so it will insert nothing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend jQuery library like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.afterif = function (param, condition) {
        if (condition) {
            $(this).after(param);
        }
        return this;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

And use it like this:

```
var insertAfter = true;
$('#whatEver').afterif($('<div />'), insertAfter);
```

Comment: You doesn't return `this`, so after your function invoked you will not be able to work with this element. Only after accessing it again.

Comment: And better is to wrap all into `this.each` before return so you can operate with all nodes with this selector, not only with first one. I mean `return this.each(function() {`

Comment: Or maybe take this one step further, and extend a generic jQuery method which also takes the jQuery method (i.e. after() in this example)?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of jQuery methods allow passing a function `func`. Often not clearly documented, but returning `undefined` from `func` is like a no-op, even in setters like `.attr('src', func)`.

(In this setter example, `func` should return whatever you want `'src'` set to otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous examples, here on stack overflow on how to check if a variable is defined.:

- [Whether a variable is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485840/whether-a-variable-is-undefined)
- [Find out if a Variable exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304066/find-out-if-a-variable-exists)
- [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)
- [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-which-method-is-better)

Then you can use break and continue to control the flow.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: I understand ternary operator and determining whether the variable is defined or not.  My uncertainty was whether I could eliminate the after() method altogether based on a condition.